# Flutter Firestore: inconsistent results using startAtDocument

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am using Flutter Firestore on the Web to do a pagination query. When I try to get the second page of the results using 'startAtDocument' the results show up with one document farther sometimes.

Here is my simple test case:

```
Future<void> loadSendQueueSIMPLETTEST(SendQueryType theType) async {
    final num PAGE_LENGTH = 3;
    ObservableList<DocumentSnapshot> sendQueueDocsLocal;

    QuerySnapshot snap;

    // We're doing an initial page query
    snap = await Firestore.instance.collection('departments')
        .document(departmentID)
        .collection('send_queue')
        .orderBy('created')
        .limit(PAGE_LENGTH)
        .getDocuments();

    sendQueueDocsLocal = new ObservableList.of(snap.documents);

    sendQueueDocsLocal.forEach((element) {
      print("GOT SEND QUEUE DOCS: ${element.documentID}");
    });

    DocumentSnapshot startDoc = sendQueueDocsLocal[2];
    print("DOING PREV QUERY startAt: ${startDoc.documentID}");
    snap = await Firestore.instance.collection('departments')
        .document(departmentID)
        .collection('send_queue')
        .orderBy('created')
        .startAtDocument(startDoc)
        .limit(PAGE_LENGTH)
        .getDocuments();

    sendQueueDocsLocal.clear();
    sendQueueDocsLocal.addAll(snap.documents);

    sendQueueDocsLocal.forEach((element) {
      print("SECOND SEND QUEUE DOCS: ${element.documentID}");
    });
    

  }
```

When I run this with
    `DocumentSnapshot startDoc = sendQueueDocsLocal[2];`
I get these output:

```
GOT SEND QUEUE DOCS: ahkiflypgVFeUgk6e3Kk
GOT SEND QUEUE DOCS: 7NtDiDR5hwSulB8SOou5
GOT SEND QUEUE DOCS: ioIXHJJKsuPXA7g5Bks2

DOING PREV QUERY startAt: ioIXHJJKsuPXA7g5Bks2

SECOND SEND QUEUE DOCS: Th3pHayGzqA1y1i3UTSf   <-- I expected this to be ioIXHJJKsuPXA7g5Bks2
SECOND SEND QUEUE DOCS: FznOTVIkPXnJi2co7yCp
SECOND SEND QUEUE DOCS: U7EtpyWIBsK6xlUJp43A
```

If I change the start document to another document (different index), like:
    `DocumentSnapshot startDoc = sendQueueDocsLocal[1];`
The results look fine:

```
GOT SEND QUEUE DOCS: ahkiflypgVFeUgk6e3Kk
GOT SEND QUEUE DOCS: 7NtDiDR5hwSulB8SOou5
GOT SEND QUEUE DOCS: ioIXHJJKsuPXA7g5Bks2

DOING PREV QUERY startAt: 7NtDiDR5hwSulB8SOou5

SECOND SEND QUEUE DOCS: 7NtDiDR5hwSulB8SOou5   <--- This looks right!
SECOND SEND QUEUE DOCS: ioIXHJJKsuPXA7g5Bks2
SECOND SEND QUEUE DOCS: Th3pHayGzqA1y1i3UTSf
```

Is there a reason startAtDocument behaves differently under some condition?